# PHP-EWS : creating a read only calendar event

Tags: php, exchangewebservices, php-ews

I'm creating calendar events as per following example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/createitem-operation-calendar-item

I'm using PHP-EWS to achieve it. My code works fine. Although, I want to make the calendar items as read only. I do not see any documentation about it.

Has anyone achieved this?

Can someone direct me to the right direction. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just learnt that you can't create read only calendar events though the API.

Ref: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/d7e2865b-759b-46bd-b267-01452f54a538/delete-appointment-restriction-using-ews?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: It is not EWS API limitation - you cannot create read-only appointments using *any* API exposed by Outlook or Exchange. Nor can you create them manually in Outlook.